# What steps we need to perform from DB end in case of storage migration?

Tags: db2, storage, db2-luw, vmware

What are the impacts / steps from DB2 DB side before VMware SvMotion Storage migration ?

Answer (score 1):

The impact should be minimal, if not non-existent. I've had several databases of varying sizes (both in storage and cluster) and types (MySQL, Postgres, Cassandra, to name a few) migrated between different storage environments with little impact to the end user. The VM always stays online and is usable just as it was prior to the vMotion.

If it's a:

- manually triggered event I would say, at minimum, have a fresh backup available somewhere off-server in case there is a problem that requires a recovery. Otherwise, watch your applications and logs on the DB server as the Storage vMotion is occurring  and react accordingly.
- automatic event because of storage failure, storage utilization, etc., you should be sure your backups are automated and saved off-server so you can recover should there be a problem. VM snapshots won't save you here should there be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answer left in a comment by [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio):

I presume [`set write suspend`](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0009503.html) should be enough.